# Splitting up code in multiple files causing `multiple definition` and `undefined reference` error

Tags: programming, linker, platformio

I have the following very basic program that reads MPU6050(accelerometer and gyroscope) sensor using the I2C library, and prints the sensor information. This program works as expected.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h>

inline void printToSerial(bool, bool) __attribute__((always_inline));

MPU6050 imu;
int16_t ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz;

void setup() {
  imu.initialize();  

  imu.setFullScaleGyroRange(MPU6050_GYRO_FS_250);
  imu.setFullScaleAccelRange(MPU6050_ACCEL_FS_2);

  imu.setXAccelOffset(-1451);
  imu.setYAccelOffset(-682);
  imu.setZAccelOffset(1448);
  imu.setXGyroOffset(69);
  imu.setYGyroOffset(-16);
  imu.setZGyroOffset(29);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {    
  imu.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);
  printToSerial(false, true);
  delay(50);
}

void printToSerial(bool a, bool g){
  if(a){
    Serial.print(ax); Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(ay); Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(az);
  }
  
  if(g){
    Serial.print(gx); Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(gy); Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(gz);
  }
}
```

But as I want to add more functionality to the main program - I want to move MPU6050 specific code to separate file.

So, I created `Sensor.h` with the following content,

```
#ifndef SENSOR_H
#define SENSOR_H

#include <MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h>

extern MPU6050 imu;
extern int16_t ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz;

void sensorInit();
void sensorUpdate();

#endif
```

And placed the implementation in the `Sensor.cpp` file.

```
# include "Sensor.h"

void sensorInit(){
  imu.initialize();  

  imu.setFullScaleGyroRange(MPU6050_GYRO_FS_250);
  imu.setFullScaleAccelRange(MPU6050_ACCEL_FS_2);

  imu.setXAccelOffset(-1451);
  imu.setYAccelOffset(-682);
  imu.setZAccelOffset(1448);
  imu.setXGyroOffset(69);
  imu.setYGyroOffset(-16);
  imu.setZGyroOffset(29);
}

void sensorUpdate(){
    imu.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);
}
```

And finally, modified the `main.cpp` file in the following way,

```
#include "Sensor.h"
#include <Arduino.h>

inline void printToSerial(bool, bool) __attribute__((always_inline));

void setup() {
  sensorInit(); // replaced few lines of codes
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {    
  sensorUpdate(); // replaced few lines of codes
  printToSerial(false, true);
  delay(50);
}

void printToSerial(bool a, bool g){
  if(a){
    Serial.print(ax); Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(ay); Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(az);
  }
  
  if(g){
    Serial.print(gx); Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(gy); Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(gz);
  }
}
```

But when I try to build the code, I get the following error in the linking step,

```
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':   
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpPacketAvailable()'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':   
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetAccel(long*, unsigned char const*)'       
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':   
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetAccel(int*, unsigned char const*)'        
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':   
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetAccel(VectorInt16*, unsigned char const*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':   
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetQuaternion(long*, unsigned char const*)'  
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetQuaternion(int*, unsigned char const*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetQuaternion(Quaternion*, unsigned char const*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetGyro(long*, unsigned char const*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetGyro(int*, unsigned char const*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetGyro(VectorInt16*, unsigned char const*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetLinearAccel(VectorInt16*, VectorInt16*, VectorFloat*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetLinearAccelInWorld(VectorInt16*, VectorInt16*, Quaternion*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetGravity(int*, unsigned char const*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetGravity(VectorFloat*, Quaternion*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetEuler(float*, Quaternion*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetYawPitchRoll(float*, Quaternion*, VectorFloat*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpProcessFIFOPacket(unsigned char const*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpReadAndProcessFIFOPacket(unsigned char, unsigned char*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetFIFOPacketSize()'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\build\uno\src\main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `MPU6050::dmpInitialize()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MPU6050::dmpGetCurrentFIFOPacket(unsigned char*)'
.pio\build\uno\src\Sensor.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.pio\libdeps\uno\I2Cdevlib-MPU6050/MPU6050.h:436:7: warning: type 'struct MPU6050' violates one definition rule [-Wodr]
 class MPU6050 {
       ^
.pio\libdeps\uno\I2Cdevlib-MPU6050\MPU6050.h:436:7: note: a different type is defined in another translation unit
 class MPU6050 {
       ^
.pio\libdeps\uno\I2Cdevlib-MPU6050/MPU6050.h:1036:18: note: the first difference of corresponding definitions is field 'dmpPacketBuffer'
         uint8_t *dmpPacketBuffer;
                  ^
.pio\libdeps\uno\I2Cdevlib-MPU6050\MPU6050.h:436:7: note: a type with different number of fields is defined in another translation unit
 class MPU6050 {
       ^
C:\Users\iamcr\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1jV0kL.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `MPU6050::getDeviceID() [clone .constprop.29]':
<artificial>:(.text+0xbba): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text+0xbd0): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text+0xbd4): undefined reference to `imu'
C:\Users\iamcr\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1jV0kL.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x10c): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x11c): undefined reference to `imu'
C:\Users\iamcr\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1jV0kL.ltrans0.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x12a): more undefined references to `imu' follow
C:\Users\iamcr\AppData\Local\Temp\cc1jV0kL.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x282): undefined reference to `ax'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x286): undefined reference to `ax'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x28a): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x28e): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x298): undefined reference to `ay'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x29c): undefined reference to `ay'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2a0): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2a4): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2ae): undefined reference to `az'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2b2): undefined reference to `az'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2b6): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2ba): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2c4): undefined reference to `gx'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2c8): undefined reference to `gx'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2cc): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2d0): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2da): undefined reference to `gy'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2de): undefined reference to `gy'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2e2): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2e6): undefined reference to `imu'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2f0): undefined reference to `gz'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x2f4): undefined reference to `gz'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x30c): undefined reference to `gy'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x310): undefined reference to `gy'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x328): undefined reference to `gz'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x32c): undefined reference to `gz'
```

Main.cpp, Sensor.cpp and Sensor.h files are in the same directory. I am using PlatformIO to build and deploy the code on an Arduino Uno and the platformio.ini file content is the following,

```
[env:uno]
platform = atmelavr
board = uno
framework = arduino
lib_deps = jrowberg/I2Cdevlib-MPU6050@0.0.0-alpha+sha.fbde122cc5
```

I am wondering what is causing the linking errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The failing is not with your code. The failing is with the MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20.h library. It erroneously has code in the header rather than in a separate CPP file.

You have done everything right. The author of that library could do well in taking a leaf out of your book.

To get it working you will have to move the code out of the header file into the .cpp file - or move it to reside inside the class definition and make it `inline`.

Comment: I would be nice if there were a feature that would tell me how many people were typing in answers, scrapping mine now.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks! I just added inline keyword before each offending method in the header file, and the resolved the multiple definition issue. I've also added `MPU6050 imu; int16_t ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz;` to global space of main.cpp to resolve the undefined reference issue.